# Почему не работает пагинация?

Tags: django

```
def listing(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 5)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:

        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:

        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render('base.html', {"posts": posts})
```

---

```
{% include 'navbar.html'%}
{% block content %}

  <div style="margin-top: 65px;">
    {% for po in page_post %}
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <h4 class="title_text">{{ po.title|truncatechars_html:100 }}</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="{% url 'post' index=po.id %}">Read</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    {% endfor %}

  </div>

  <div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
      {% if posts.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
      {% endif %}

      <span class="current">
        Page {{ posts.number }} of {{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}.
      </span>

      {% if posts.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
      {% endif %}
    </span>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

всё сделал как в офф документации, но почему-то вы браузере вот такая картина выходит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы что-то не договариваете. Вы в шаблон передаёте только `posts`, но при этом цикл проходится по переменной `page_post`, которой, получается, не существует и посты не должны выводиться вообще, а они у вас почему-то выводятся. Вы уверены, что страница, которая изображена на скриншоте, создаётся именно указанной вьюхой и именно указанным шаблоном?

Comment: Для вывода постов другая вьюха

Comment: Ваш коммент вот вообще не отвечает на мой вопрос. Ещё раз: страница, которая изображена на скриншоте, точно-точно-преточно создаётся именно вьюхой `listing`?

Comment: Нет, она создаётся другой вьюхой

Comment: Ну вот и всё. Другая вьюха не передаёт объект с пагинации `posts` — вот и не работает ваша пагинация, вопрос можно закрывать